# Check if function can be called: Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, timer

I'm trying to write a Javascript function that calls doSomething() continuously, as long as some_condition is true. If some_condition becomes false, it should check after five seconds whether some_condition has again become true, and if not, display an error message on the screen.

I currently have this much of the function written, but am confused about whether I am doing this correctly. Thanks for the help.

```
while (some_condition) {
  doSomething();
  else {
    ???
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you should not use a `while` loop. JavaScript is single threaded, and if you have a `while` loop that never returns, the browser (or your JavaScript environment of choice) will become unresponsive.

You need to use `setTimeout` to schedule the function.

```
function enqueueSomething() {
  if (some_condition)
    doSomething();
    // Enqueue ourselves to run again without blocking the thread of execution
    setTimeout(enqueueSomething);
  else
    // Wait 5 seconds, then try again
    setTimeout(enqueueSomething, 5000);
}
```

You'll need to maintain some state that indicates whether you've previously waiting 5 seconds, and add your error-alerting code.

Comment: Could you explain under what conditions while loops should not be used in JavaScript? Is it just when there's a possibility that the code inside a while loop would take a long time to execute?

Comment: @codersun3 That's exactly it. If your `while` loop runs for more than a fraction of a second, the entire browser will become unresponsive.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to change the code so that, if some_condition is false, it only checks once after five seconds whether some_condition is true? It should not continue to check after 10, 15, 20 etc. seconds whether some_condition is true.